# Loading MATLAB object from a file

Tags: matlab, oop, object

In MATLAB I am loading my custom class object from a file. It contains references to other files that should be located on the drive next to the object file. Is there a way to get the location of the file from which the object is loaded during the initialization?

Example:

- My object file is C:\user\myObjectFile.mat
- I load it from a script: load('C:\user\myObjectFile.mat')
- I want the object to be able to know that it was loaded from the specified file

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom load function, i.e.

```
function obj = loadMyObj( filepath )
    data = load( filepath );
    obj = data.obj; % load returns the object "obj" in a struct
    obj.filepath = filepath;
end
```

Then use `loadMyObj` instead of `load`.

Of course this requires your object to have the `filepath` property, but that's a given if you want it to retain the location it was loaded from.

Another alternative could be to but this behaviour into the class constructor for your object, then call something like

```
obj = myClass( 'C:\some\path\file.mat' );
```

Where the constructor loads the file, assigns the properties stored in the file, and stores the path too.

Comment: Hi, I have tried using loadobj before, but I was not able to propagate the information about the file (its fullpath) to the object level. I have a GUI where I choose the objects stored as files I want to manipulate, within by GUI I am using load('C:\user\myObjectFile.extension','-mat') - with custom file extension. I am not able to propagate the fullpath of the file to the object level - I thought I could use loadobj to customize the object recreation proces, but I could not get it to work. I know that I do have the information available within the GUI, but I want the object to store it also.

Comment: @Vlad Note I'm not using `loadobj`, I'm just calling a custom function `loadMyObj` which calls the normal load (you could change this to `load( filepath, '-mat')`) and then assigns the file path property to your object.

Comment: Coming back very late, but this indeed has solved my problem. Thanks a lot!